# What is the correct way to take input as a string. I want to print a character at 'i' which is entered by user

Tags: java

The output and error my code is showing:

```
Enter string : hii'

8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkIndex(String.java:4828)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:46)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1555)
    at string_methods.main(string_methods.java:9)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Suggest me the corrections and also please explain why this error occurred. My code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class string_methods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter string : ");
        String str = sc.next();
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Char at "+i+" is "+str.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're trying to print character number 8 (0-based, so actually the 9th character) from a string which only has 4 characters (hii'). It's unclear to me what output you expected.

Comment: Check if `i` is within the range of characters in the string. Loop if it's not, and you want the user to try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter string : ");
    String str = sc.next();
    int i;
    while (true) {
        i = sc.nextInt();
    //you can handle floating point and very big numbers as well 
        if (i >= str.length() && i > -1)
            System.out.println("Enter a valid index : ");
        else break;
    }
    System.out.println("Char at " + i + " is " + str.charAt(i));
```

Comment: BTW a negative is also not a valid index...

Answer (score 1):

The code in [Answer by AMZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77339011/642706) is correct for some strings, but fails with most characters. For example, try `"".length()`.

Instead of using `char`, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

The key to solving your problem is validating your user’s input: Did the user input a position number that is not too small or too large?

```
System.out.print("Enter string : ");
String s = sc.next();
System.out.print("Enter the position of desired character : ");
int position ;
while (true) {
    i = sc.nextInt();
    if ( ( position < 1 ) || ( position > s.codePoints().count() ) )
        System.out.println( "Enter a valid position number : " );
    else break;
}
int codePoint = s.codePoints().toArray()[ position - 1 ] ;  // Subtract one for annoying zero-based index number. 
String result = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
System.out.println("Character at position " + position + " is " + result );
```

---

Also, be aware that what appears to be a single character may actually be a composite of several. For example, what appears to be a single emoji character of a human hand may actually be composed of multiple characters that act as modifiers to indicate a particular skin tone. Text-handling is a tricky subject.

Comment: @user85421 I meant for the  logic here to use common sense  1-based ordinals, not 0-based index. Now fixed, thank you.

Comment: @user85421 Yes! Thank you. Fixed. I need coffee ☕️.